# On Mobile device jQuery Touch select div's in random order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-touch-punch

On Mobile device I want to select specific `div` w.r.t. `touch` ie. when user touch on `first div` and `touchmove` to `3rd div` then these both div's need to be selected. Like vise the order can be random 1 3 2 4, 1 2 3 4

The attached image will give better understanding

1 3 2 Selection

[image: 1 3 2 Selection]

1 2 3 selection

[image]

I have also created `jsfiddle` for the same with what I have done till. You can check it at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mujaffar/m03g52ah/). I am using jquery mobile also trying to use `touch` and `touchmove` events but it's not working as per my requirement.

Please help me in this, Thanks

Comment: Why you dont use `vclick/vmousemove` if you're using jquery-mobile? That handles both of event-types (desktop/mobile). The current type you can check in `originalEvent`. See your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m03g52ah/7/

Comment: Thanks -- But it actually required to tap to each div. Didn't it work when we tap (touch) 1st div and touch-moved finger to 2nd and then 3rd div -- That actually need to highlight 1st 2nd and 3rd

Comment: Yes, sure, it was not the complete solution for your problem, just an attempt how you can solve it. :-) Count your `<sections>` and check which current `<section>`is selected (touched). Now you can compare the `.index()` of your current target and the count of `<section>`. Here you build a little logic which checks which element have to highlight and is already highlighted.

Comment: Take a look here, its absolutly quick&dirty and should only give you a attempt to solve it yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/m03g52ah/11/

Answer (score 0):

Its not really clear (for me) what you want.
Here is a really simple attempt for you which maybe will help your self to solve your issue.

**Checkout this Snippet**

**EDIT:** Updated, now works also which (v)touchmove

```js
$(function() {
  $(".section").on('vclick', function(e) {
    $('.logs').html('eventType: ' + e.originalEvent.type);
    $(this).addClass('green');
    toHighlightElements($(this), $(".section"));
  })

  $(".sections-wrapper").on('vmousemove', function(e) {
    $('.logs').html('eventType: ' + e.originalEvent.type);
    
    var $target;
    if(e.originalEvent.type === 'touchmove') {
      e.preventDefault();
      $target = getActiveElement($(".section"), e.clientX, e.clientY);
      if(typeof $target === 'undefined') {
        return;
      }
    }
    else {
      $target = $(e.target);
    }
    
    toHighlightElements($target, $(".section"));
  });
  
  function toHighlightElements($current, $overall) {
    for (var i = 0 ; i <= $current.index() ; i++) {
     $overall.eq(i).addClass('green');
    }
  }
  
  function getActiveElement($overallElements, x, y) {
      return $(document.elementFromPoint(x, y));
  }  
  
  $('.reset').click(function() {
    $(".section").removeClass('green');
  });
});
```

```css
.section {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: grey;
}

.green {
  background-color: green !important;
}

.allowLeft {
  float: left;
}

.sections-wrapper {
  background: red;
  width: 105px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js">
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>

<div class="sections-wrapper">

  <div class="section allowLeft">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="section allowLeft">
    2
  </div>

  <div class="section allowLeft">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="section allowLeft">
    4
  </div>
  
   <br style="clear: both" />
</div>
<br><br>
<button class="reset">
reset
</button>

<div class="logs">
</div>
```

Updated also your jsfiddle: `https://jsfiddle.net/m03g52ah/12/`